# How to use google apps script to validate a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have been trying to write this code to validate a range of cells. If the cells contain the text "true" then set value as "Incorrect Data" else "DD Data"

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function myFunction() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();


  for (var i = 1; i<10; i++) {

   var workingcell = activeSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    if( workingcell == "TRUE" ) { 

       activeSheet.getRange(i,2).setValue("Incorrect Data");
       }

  else {activeSheet.getRange(i,2).setValue("DD Data");}    

}
}
```

The code is executing without compilation error but it is not able to recognize the cell values because it is mark "DD Data" for all the cells which is incorrect. If the cell value is "TRUE" then -- "Incorrect Data" else "DD Data

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Also it could be a good idea to describe what does the code included and if there is a problem with it.

Comment: I have been trying to write this code to validate a range of cells. If the cells contain the text "true" then set value as "Incorrect Data" else "DD Data"

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Does it throws an error? How are you running it?

Comment: @Rubén : The code is executing without compilation error but it is not able to recognize the cell values because it is mark "DD Data" for all the cells which is incorrect.

If the cell value is "TRUE" then -- "Incorrect Data"
else "DD Data"

Answer (score 1):

Choose one of the following options

1. instead of `getValue()` use `getDisplayValue()` 
   the first return a boolean for a Google Sheets `TRUE`/`FALSE` values while the second returns a string
2. instead of `"TRUE"` use `true`
   `true` is the JavaScript equivalent for Google Sheets `TRUE`

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, I have a question.

if I wanted to check a cell for a date, how would i do that?
Like for example if isdate(C1) = true then do this.